# Hide a menu item for a joomla component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, menu

when creating a menu for a component there shows a selection either for a list to show or an individual page. I need to hide the individual selection of page as menu.. How can I hide this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it:

**First**

To hide whole view (including different layouts), go to your view directory, and find file `metadata.xml`. Add `hidden="true"` to `<view>` tag.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <view title="View title" hidden="true">
        <message><![CDATA[View description]]></message>
    </view>
</metadata>
```

**Second**

To hide only specific layout of view, go to same views subdirectory `tmpl`, find your layout specific `.xml` file (`layoutname.xml`). Add `hidden="true"` to `<layout>` tag.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="Layout title" option="View" hidden="true>
        <message>
            <![CDATA[Layout description]]>
        </message>
    </layout>
</metadata>
```